# Bind IPv6 address to Python socket as source ip address

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ipv6

I formerly used the code below to bind IPv4 address to Python socket as source ip address.

```
import socket
true_socket = socket.socket
def bound_socket(*a, **k):
    sock = true_socket(*a, **k)
    sock.bind((sourceIP, 0))
    return sock
socket.socket = bound_socket
```

Does above code work for IPv6 address? If not, how can I bind an IPv6 address?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this, to get an IPV6 address, it is recommend that you use `socket.getaddrinfo` it will return all the different address both IPV4 and IPV6, you can bind them all or just which ever one you want/need.

```
import socket
def bound_socket(*a, **k):
    sock = socket.socket(*a, **k)
    if socket.AF_INET6 in a:
        if not socket.has_ipv6:
            raise ValueError("There's no support for IPV6!")
        else:
            address = [addr for addr in socket.getaddrinfo(source_ip, None)
                        if socket.AF_INET6 == addr[0]] # You ussually want the first one.
            if not address:
                raise ValueError("Couldn't find ipv6 address for source %s" % source_ip)
            sock.bind(address[0][-1])
    else:
        sock.bind((source_ip, 0))
    return sock
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want an extensive solution, you could extend your solution to use `getaddrinfo()`:

```
import socket
l = socket.getaddrinfo(None, "", 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
for i in l: print i
```

This gives

```
(2, 1, 6, '', ('0.0.0.0', 0))
(10, 1, 6, '', ('::', 0, 0, 0))
```

These are the parameters you should create a socket with:

```
s = socket.socket(i[0], i[1], i[2])
if i[0] == AF_INET6: s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_V6ONLY, 1)
s.bind(i[4])
```

Now you have as many sockets as you have protocols and you can use them. (Alas, the `IPV6_V6ONLY` doesn't work under older Windows versions...)

If you have a given host name/IP to bind to, do

```
l = socket.getaddrinfo("mylocalIP", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
```

and it will choose the correct address/protocol family for you:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("::1", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('::1', 0, 0, 0))]
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 0))]
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('::1', 0, 0, 0)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 0))]
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("192.168.1.32", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('192.168.1.32', 0))]
```

etc.

`2` vs `10` are `AF_INET` vs. `AF_INET6`; `socket.AI_PASSIVE` means that you need this address for `bind()`ing.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick... set the address family.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET6)
s.bind(('::1', 1234))
```